# Tyoescript error, Types of property xxx are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am defind my state:

```
  const [reminderInfo, setReminderInfo] = useState<{
    reminderButtonText: string | undefined;
    reminderUrl: string | undefined;
  }>({
    reminderButtonText: '',
    reminderUrl: '',
  });
```

When I try and pass the prop to my component:

```
  <Component
         
          reminderInfo={reminderInfo}
    
        />
```

Error:

> Type '{ reminderButtonText: string | undefined; reminderUrl: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ reminderButtonText: string; reminderUrl: string; }'.
> Types of property 'reminderButtonText' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

`string | undefined` is not assignable to type `string`? I have defined my type as,`string | undefined`

Component:

```
type Props = {

  reminderInfo: {
    reminderButtonText: string | '';
    reminderUrl: string | '';
  };
};
const VehicleSummaryCard: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({

  reminderInfo,
}) => {
...
```

Comment: What is the type you have assigned for `reminderInfo` in `Component`. It's like you haven't added the full types to other type definitions using `reminderInfo`

Comment: Yes you've defined it as `string | undefined`, but clearly you're passing it to something that wants `string`. The compiler is telling you exactly the right thing: that's unsafe, as the recipient will always treat it as a string, even though it might not be.

Comment: `string | ''` - either a string or... a string?!